# 「ファイルの名前から拡張子を除いた部分」を表す名詞はありますか?

Tags: 英語, file

例えば、 `foobar.jpeg` というファイル名があったときに、拡張子を除いた部分、つまりこの例でいうならば `foobar` を表す名詞はありますか?

より具体的には、 `path/to/somefile.ext` から `somefile` を抜き出す関数を定義しようとして、これはどういう命名をすれば良いのだろう、と疑問に思ったので、質問しています。

Comment: Python の pathlib では [stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)

Comment: 参考: [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053)

Comment: VS Codeでは [fileBasenameNoExtension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) (Extensionは suffixと呼ぶことも)

Comment: MSVCだと部分毎に関数があるのではなく、1つで全て分ける形ですね。[_splitpath, _wsplitpath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Emacs Lisp の場合は [file-name-base](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html#index-file_002dname_002dbase)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) の `System.IO.Path` [解説文書](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0) においては `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` と命名されているようです。

[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) 系での似たようなコマンドラインツールとして `basename` というのがあります。

```
$ basename path/to/foo.tar.gz .gz
foo.tar
$ basename path/to/foo.tar.gz .tar.gz
foo
$
```

`foo.tar.gz` の拡張子（あるいは拡張子を除いたファイル名）が何かは、この手の分離ツールを作る側と使う側で事前の合意が必要そうです（ `basename` は使う側が指定しろということらしい）

Comment: 複数拡張子がある場合ややこしいですね。metropolisさんの紹介された`stem`もC++の[`std::filesystem::path::stem()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/filesystem/path/stem.html)も最後の拡張子しか取り除きません。名称よりも技術的にはその方が便利だからだとは思います。そうなると`basename`のように「利用者が求める拡張子を取り除いた残りを返す」が最も合致するような気がします。

Answer (score 0):

> ファイルの名前から拡張子を除いた部分を表す名詞はありますか?

- 本体
- 本体名
- ファイルの本体名

---

何かいい呼び方がないか調べたことがありますがぴったりとした名前が見つかりませんでした。
結局、ファイル名から「.拡張子」を除いたものということが多いです。